# GLSL Arrays and Multiple Light Sources for Per-fragment Lighting

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have got this simple GLSL shader running which does per-fragment lighting to models. Everything works fine, but a problem occurs when I try using more than a single light source for my scene. In order to do per-fragment lighting with many light sources, one shall for-loop through a light sources array, calculate the contribution for each Ambient, Diffuse and Specular color and add the values together. Now the moment I changed my light properties's variables to be arrays instead, performance plummeted.

Have a look at the following fragment shader:

```
#version 130
#define MAX_LIGHT_COUNT 8

int lSourcesCount;
float lIntensity[MAX_LIGHT_COUNT];
vec3 lPosition[MAX_LIGHT_COUNT];
vec3 lDirection[MAX_LIGHT_COUNT];
vec3 lAmbient[MAX_LIGHT_COUNT];
vec3 lDiffuse[MAX_LIGHT_COUNT];
vec3 lSpecular[MAX_LIGHT_COUNT];

float mShininess;
vec3 mAmbient;
vec3 mDiffuse;
vec3 mSpecular;

#if __VERSION__ > 130
    in vec4 InterPosition;
    in vec3 InterNormal;
    in vec4 InterColor;

    out vec3 gl_FragColor;
#else
    varying vec4 InterPosition;
    varying vec4 InterColor;
    varying vec3 InterNormal;
#endif

void set_temp_light_values()
{
    lSourcesCount = 1;

    lPosition[0] = vec3(0.0, 2.0, -2.0);

    lAmbient[0] = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    lDiffuse[0] = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    lSpecular[0] = vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);


    mShininess = 16;
    mAmbient = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    mDiffuse = vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    mSpecular = vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
}

void main()
{
    set_temp_light_values();

    vec3 normal = normalize(InterNormal);

    int i = 0;

    vec3 surfaceToLight = normalize(lPosition[i] - InterPosition.xyz);
    vec3 cameraToSurface = normalize(-lPosition[i].xyz);

    float diffuseCont = max(dot(normal, surfaceToLight), 0);

    vec3 reflection = -reflect(surfaceToLight, normal);
    float specularCont = max(dot(reflection, cameraToSurface), 0);
    specularCont = pow(specularCont, mShininess);

    vec3 ambient = lAmbient[i] * mAmbient;
    vec3 diffuse = (lDiffuse[i] * mDiffuse) * diffuseCont;
    vec3 specular = (lSpecular[i] * mSpecular) * specularCont;


    gl_FragColor = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0);
}
```

This line in particular `int i = 1;` is the index of my light source which I will be doing the looping using in my for loop. Using `const int i = 1;` instead will apparently cause the compiler to optimize the array out and just make variables instead. Without the `const`, the program FPS drops down from over 100 to ~20.

**Why are arrays so slow in GLSL shaders, and what is the workaround for using multiple light sources without suffering from that slowdown?**

Comment: use uniforms for the light parameters, and don't  try to dynamically initialize arrays per fragment, otherwise you'll end up with a copy of this data per shader invocation, working against the GPU architecture for no benefit at all.

Comment: Aah! Right. I seem to always forget how many times fragment shaders can run when rendering a scene. Using a uniform will probably yield a different result. Thanks!